# How to hide the text that is located after a button - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to hide the button AND text when the button is clicked on. I have it hiding the button, but I can't get my click event to hide the text within a li and p tag.

This is the Javascript/jQuery code I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#add").click(function() {
        var html = "";

        $("ul").append("<br>" + '<input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">');

        html += "<li>" + $("#task").val() + "</li>";
        $("ul").append(html);
        $("#task").val("");
    }); // end click

    $(".delete").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this)..hide();

    }); //end delete click

}); // end ready
```

This is the HTML code that I am trying to manipulate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Task List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="tasks.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <aside>
        <h2>Add a task</h2>
        <label for="task">Task:</label>
        <input type="text" id="task" name="task"><br>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add Task"> 
    </aside>
    <main>
        <h1>Task list</h1>
        <ul>
            <input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">
            <p><li>Wash car</li></p>

            <input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">
            <p><li>Fertilize lawn</li></p>

            <input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">
            <p><li>Clean out refrigerator</li></p>
        </ul>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: That html is invalid. `<li>` must be child of `<ul>` or `<ol>` .... `<input>` and `<p>` may not be children of `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @charlietfl your HTML is invalid, but you can use jQuery [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next `<p>` element;

```
 $(".delete").click(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.hide();
     $this.next('p').hide();
 });
```

If your html would be valid and be among the lines of;

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">
    <p>Wash car</p></li>

    <li><input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">
    <p>Fertilize lawn</p></li>

    <li><input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">
    <p>Clean out refrigerator</p></li>
</ul>
```

On button click you could hide the parent `<li>` and this would hide both text and button at the same time;

```
 $(".delete").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().hide();
 });
```

**UPDATE BASED ON A COMMENT**

If you dynamically add a element to a website, you can't use .click() as it does not bind to elements that have been added after the script execution. You have to use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can for example bind this to body and listen for clicks that match your selector;

```
 $("body").on("click", ".delete", function(){
     $(this).parent().hide();
     // OR DEPENDS ON THE HTML YOU GO WITH
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.hide();
     $this.next('p').hide();
 });
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to use the valid HTML you should update your add function as well to append valid list elements, e.g.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var html = "";

    var button = '<input type="button" class="delete" value="Task Complete">';
    var taskText = '<p>' + $("#task").val() + '</p>'

    html += "<li>" + button + taskText + "</li>";
    $("ul").append(html);
    $("#task").val("");
});
```

Comment: That works with the current tasks I have, but when I try to add a new button with text through jQuery, I can't hide the new task.

Comment: Hi, please see my update on the answer to fix your issues with the dynamically added elements.

Comment: That provided code still won't work. Is it supposed to be .button or just button? cause .button says this as a class?

Comment: Hi its supposed to be the selector so in this case ´.delete`, sorry :) Updated the answer

Comment: I actually changed it from .button to .delete! Thank you so much for your help. I just have one more issue. When I dynamically add another element and I want to hide that dynamically added element, it hides the entire list. Is there something wrong when I create the element??

Comment: Depends what sort of an HTML structure you are using. Did you update it to valid as I posted or are you using the original version?

Comment: Yes, I switched around the <li> and <p> tags, like you had showed.

Comment: Hi,

Then you need to also update the add function, please see my update 2. You are appending the dynamic elements with the invalid HTML structure so the delete buttons remove the <ul> as its their parent instead of the <li>

Comment: OHHH, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you so much for your help! I'm still just learning jQuery and there's so much to learn.

Comment: No worries, glad to see people getting into world programming! Would appreciate if you would accept my answer, so others know this issue is now solved. You can do that by: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."